# Объясните почему ошибка

Tags: c#

Не могу понять почему это не работает, ведь kt1 и kt2 присвоился тип double и метод math возвращает переменной hypot double так почему же программа выводит число 20 если должно 6.203... и откуда программа взяла число 20???

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uMpIh.png]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Поставьте "плюс" вместо "звездочки" между квадратами катетов.

Comment: Я в шоке, невнимательно подошел к заданию, спасибо!

Comment: @СашаКульчицкий Пожалуйста. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.